# is saying (innaka la tukhliful mi’ad) in the dua after Adhaan is innovation?

Tags: hadith, dua, bidah, adhan

This dua is to be recited after adhaan

> Allahumma rabba hadhihi-d-da’awati-t-tammati wa-s-Salati-l-qa’imati,
> ati Muhammadan il-wasilata wa-l-fadilata (wa-d-darajata-r-rafi’ati)
> wa-b‘ath-hu maqamam mahmudan illadhi wa‘adtahu

Reference    : [Sahih al-Bukhari 614](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/10/12)

But almost everyone adds this extra verse when reciting that is not part of the dua.

> (innaka la tukhliful mi’ad)

I heard that this is an innovation, since it's not part of the dua. Like some say `sadaqallahul azim` after reciting Quran.

So is saying **(innaka la tukhliful mi’ad)** with that dua an innovation?

Comment: From which perspective are you speaking? It certainly is not bid'ah as Allah Himself used this expression in a du'a in qur'an in surat Aal-'Imraan.

Comment: Searching on google it addressed [here](https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/35197/ruling-of-adding-innaka-laa-tukhliful-meeaad%E2%80%A6-ad-darajah-ar-rafeeah-after-the-athaan) and [here](https://hadithanswers.com/the-complete-dua-that-is-recited-after-adhan/) that it is an uncommon addition present in the Sunan of [Bayhaqi](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33024/2198#p1). Also as @Medi1Saif said the phrase itself is in the Quran in [3:194](https://quran.com/3/194).

Answer (score 0):

إِنَّكَ لَا تُخلِفُ المِيعِاد

This addition was weakened by [al-Albani](https://www.al-albany.com/audios/content/142024/%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%A9-%D8%A3%D9%86%D9%83-%D9%84%D8%A7-%D8%AA%D8%AE%D9%84%D9%81-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%AF-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D9%87%D8%B0%D9%87-%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%AF%D8%AA-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%A8%D8%B9%D8%B6-%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%AE%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%8A), [Shu'aib al-Arna'ut](https://dorar.net/h/Cn4cEQib), [Abdullah as-Sa'd](https://youtu.be/B1dppH7i4Ew), [Mustafa al-Adwi](https://youtu.be/FREK_4Cj48g), [al-Harith al-Hasani](https://t.me/alhasany/691) and [Sulayman al-Alwan](https://youtu.be/Ma1hNIKqhvQ).

Muhammad bin 'Awf Al-Ta'i was alone in narrating this addition. The hadith was narrated by (al-Alwan said, "more than 11 narrators".) senior memorizers of ahadith including Ahmad bin Hanbal, Ibn Ali al-Madini, Bukhari and others, without the addition of "innaka la tukhliful mi'aad". So this addition is shadh (anomalous), not authentic.

Comment: The addition of a [trustworthy narrator](https://thesunnahstudies.wordpress.com/2021/06/23/methodological-differences-between-early-vs-later-scholars-of-%e1%b8%a5adith-part-4-the-addition-of-a-trustworthy-narrator/) isn't always authentic, you actually have to look into it if it's authentic or not. The later scholars were very lenient in this matter so they generally authenticated additions. So no attention should be paid to those who came later and authenticated this hadith.

Comment: سؤال(2) هل يوجد فرق بين زيادة الثقة وتفرد الثقة؟

زيادة الثقة هي ما يرويه الثقة زيادة على غيره من الثقات، وهذه الزيادة هي تفرد من هذا الثقة زادها على من شاركه في رواية الحديث نفسه عن الشيخ، وهذه الزيادة لا تقبل مطلقًا ولا تُرَدّ مطلقًا، وإنما نتبع في ذلك القرائن، فقد تقبل وقد ترد، وأما تفرد الثقة إن كان القصد هو ما يتفرد به عمن شاركه في الرواية عن شيخه؛ فهي نفسها زيادة الثقة، وإن كان المقصود تفرد الثقة بحديث ما؛ فإن كان ممن يُحتمل تفرده فيقبل حديثه وإلا فلا.
 #المائة_الأولى_من_الأَجوبة_الحايكية_على_الأسئلة الحديثية

Comment: Forgot to mention, al-Hasanî said that the entire hadīth is defective. Listen to his telegram voice note for more details. Wallahu alam.